# Three.js: Converting Equirectangular (Spherical) Panorama to 6 Cube Map

Tags: javascript, three.js, 360-panorama

I plan to add equirectangular (or spherical) panorama support on top of existing 6 cube panorama. I found this library that easily does it by converting equirectangular image to 6 cubes:

https://github.com/spite/THREE.EquirectangularToCubemap

where we can simply use `equiToCube.convert( texture, 1024 )`:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load( 'equirectangular-panorama.jpg', function( res ) {
    var equiToCube = new EquirectangularToCubemap( renderer );  
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
       new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 10, 3, 100, 32 ),
       new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: equiToCube.convert( res, 1024 ) } )
    );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

Seems simple. However, my 6 cube method to load images looks like this:

```
function getTextureCube(path, step, total){
  var urls = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg"];
  var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
  var maxAnisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  var textureCube = loader.load(urls, function(texture){
        texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        texture.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.repeat.x = -1;
    }, function ( xhr ) {
        log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    }, function ( xhr ) {
        log( 'error loading texture', xhr );
    });
  return textureCube;
}
```

And I cannot successfully utilize `equiToCube.convert( texture, 1024 )` for conversion which results in black screen instead of panorama.

```
function getEquirectangularTextureCube(path, step, total){
   var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(); // Note TextureLoader
   var maxAnisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
   var equiToCube = new EquirectangularToCubemap( renderer );
   var textureCube = loader.load(path, function(texture){
      texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      texture.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
      texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.repeat.x = -1;
   }, function ( xhr ) {
      log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
   }, function ( xhr ) {
      log( 'error loading texture', xhr );
   });
   return equiToCube.convert( textureCube, 2048 );  // Note .convert
}
```

A few thoughts to help: this returned texture is used in fragment shader and uniforms if that helps with answer. Also, I may be using equiToCube incorrectly - I did using it inside `loader.load` but unsuccessfully.

Any ideas how to integrate equirectangular (or spherical) panorama support will be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the THREE.CubeMapCamera.

Comment: I cannot find what you suggested. I can only find  https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/CubeCamera. But if that's the same why should I use that versus just converting panorama itself?

Comment: Because you can convert it at runtime basically instantly, and cubemaps are more of a standard for 3d stuff since you can then also use them as environment/reflection maps.

Also, your code looks jankey upon deeper inspection. You need to do the equiCube.convert Inside the loaded handler for the texture load. You're firing off the load and then trying to convert the texture before it's loaded.

Comment: CubemapCamera is nice because you can also bake your own scene geometry on top.. like having distant building/mountain geometries out near the horizon, which then get baked into the cubemap, so you don't have to render them until they get closer.

Comment: Anyway.. whatever works. I think your problem was just where you were calling the converter....